# How to rename the name of attribute in a node of xml in java using dom parser

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an xml as below :

```
<XML> 
  <school title="abc">  
</XML>
```

I am parsing the above xml using DOM PArser .

Now while parsing I need to rename the **title** of **school** node to **schoolname**.

Can any one help me how we can achieve using dom parser?

Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, including any code you have written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Element.getAttribute` to get the current value.

Use `Element.removeAttribute` to remove the old `title`.

Use `Element.setAttribute` to add the `schoolname` attribute.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html